# In Swift, how to get the true size of an `Any` variable?

Tags: swift, types, size

I want to be able to get the size of the underlying data type of an `Any` variable in Swift. I expected this to be possible by running `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: anyObject)`, but that expression always returns `32`, regardless of the the underlying data type of the `Any` object. I assume `32` is the size of the internal `Any` construct/type, which holds metadata about the object it stores.

How do I get the underlying data type's size?

```swift
let regularInt: Int = 1
let anyInt: Any = Int(2) as Any

MemoryLayout<Int>.size                 // 4
MemoryLayout<type(of: anyInt)>.size    // Can't do that

MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: regularInt) // 4
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: anyInt)     // 32

// How do I get size "4" out of `anyInt`?
```

Comment: Why do you want to know that? What are you intending to do with that information? Or is it pure curiosity?

Comment: @MartinR I am passing an `[Any]` array to a function, which converts each of the array's element into `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` by `UnsafeMutableRawPointer(array[i])`. To process the pointer data, I must know the size of the underlying data. I could pass another array with explicit sizes, but it is nowhere near as elegant and it's also error-prone. Do you think there is a better way to accomplish what I want to do? The `[Any]` array holds "basic" data types, such as `Int`, `Float`, `Int16`, etc.

Comment: I don't think the pointer operators would work as expected on `Any`. Recommending to use some more structured data types instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll begin with some technical details about the limitations of `Any` in this case.

So, what is `Any`? It's an empty protocol to which every type implicitly conforms to.

And how does the compiler represent variables of protocol types? It's by wrapping the actual value in an existential container. So basically when you're referencing a variable of this kind, you're actually talking to the container (well, actually not you, but the compiler is :).

An existential container has a layout that can be represented like this C structure:

```cpp
struct OpaqueExistentialContainer {
  void *fixedSizeBuffer[3];
  Metadata *type;
  WitnessTable *witnessTables[NUM_WITNESS_TABLES];
};
```

The container elements are greatly explained in [this document](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst#existential-container-layout), I'll also try to summarize them here:

- `fixedSizeBuffer` either holds the whole value, if it takes less than 24 bytes, or holds a pointer to a heap allocated zone, containing the value
- `type` is a pointer to the type metadata
- `witnessTables` is what makes this layout occupy various sizes, as the number of protocol witness tables can vary from zero to virtually any number of protocols.

So, with the above in mind:

- `Any` needs no witness tables, thus it occupies 32 bytes
- a single protocol variable occupies 40 byes
- a composed protocol variable occupies 32 + N*8, where N is the number of "independent" protocols involved in the composition

Note that the above is true if there are no class protocols involved, if a class protocol is involved, then the existential container layout is a little bit simplified, this is also better described in the [linked document](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst#class-existential-containers) from above.

---

Now, back to the problem from the question, it's the existential container created by the compiler the one which prevents you from accessing the actual type. The compiler doesn't make this structure available, and transparently translates any calls to protocol requirements to dispatches through the witness tables stored in the container.

But, might I ask you, why are you circulating `Any`? I assume you don't want to handle all possible and future types in a generic manner. A marker protocol might help here:

```swift
protocol MemoryLayouted { }

extension MemoryLayouted {
    var memoryLayoutSize: Int { MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: self) }
}
```

Then all you have left to do is to add conformance for the types you want to support:

```swift
extension Int: MemoryLayouted { }
extension String: MemoryLayouted { }
extension MyAwesomeType: MemoryLayouted { }
```

With the above in mind, you can rewrite your initial code to something like this:

```swift
let regularInt: Int = 1
let anyInt: MemoryLayouted = 2

print(regularInt.memoryLayoutSize) // 8
print(anyInt.memoryLayoutSize)     // 8
```

You get consistent behaviour and type safety, a type safety that might translate to a more stable application.

---

P.S. A hacky approach, that allows you to use `Any`, might pe possible by unpacking the existential container via direct memory access. The Swift ABI is stable at this point, so the existential container layout is guaranteed not to change in the future, however not recommending going that route unless absolutely necessary.

Maybe someone that stumbles this question and has experience in the ABI layout code can provide the code for it.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, which presents a clean way to solve my problem. In addition, you provided in-depth details, which I appreciate very much, thank you!

Comment: Any idea why Swift uses buffer of size 3 * pointerSize by default? Is it some sort of optimisation to avoid heap allocation for certain small structs?

Comment: @MaksimGayduk yes, it's a performance optimization, so that small enough structs to not require heap allocations (which is an expensive operation).

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is cast Any to all supported types. Why would you cast Int as `Any` when you know what type is it! anyway?

```swift
var value: Any = Int(2) as Any

switch value {

case value is Int:
// ... other cases here
}
```

Comment: The problem I had was that there is an `[Any]` array with different types in it. I described the situation in more detail in a comment under my question. Casting to all supported types would be an option, but I feel like @Cristik provided a more elegant solution.

Comment: @martin yes, he did ;)